# Is there a way to have a public method, which won't be inherited?

Tags: c#, php, oop, design-patterns

I have a class, with public API.
I have other classes who inherit from that class.
I do not make use of all the APIs inherited from the first class.

If I change the order of inheritance, then I have even more API methods I do not wish classes to inherit.

Languages: PHP and C#

Comment: Which language? And it sounds like you are badly misusing inheritance.

Comment: I believe that would defeat the purpose of inheritence.  If you inherit something, you gain its shape (methods, properties, etc) and can extend and/or override certain parts of it.  In most languages, even if you could hide it, it could probably still be cast to the base type and you would still have access to all the methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Answer (score 4):

Is there any specific reason why you would want such method? I think you should consider putting the functionality you want your classes to inherit in an interface. Other functionality should be implemented as private methods.

Also consider breaking down the functionality into several classes and then using Composition instead of inheritance. If you use inheritance to compose complex class hierarchies, they will always be difficult to manage. [You should favor composition over inheritance](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html).

Answer (score 4):

If some method should not be in inherited class, you probably should not place its in base class. 
Second class could implement some interface which has that method, or inherit by another class which has that method and is inherited by current base-class.

Answer (score 1):

If we call the base class B and the derived classes D1, D2...

Two approaches are:

- Split B into two classes: the private implementation (abstract B) and the public methods (that you wish to hide in your other 2 classes), D3. So to "use" the base class you instantiate D3. Then D1,D2 only inherit the private implementation of B because the public interface for "B" is only available through D3. (If you still need some of the public functionality in D1,D2 but don't want it to be public, then simply add it as a private method od B, and then add a public proxy method in D3 that exposes it and simply calls down to the base class implementation.
- Don't derive your classes from B. Embed an instance of B in D1,D2 and simply expose a new interface in those classes that only makes the "limited functionality" available.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not make use of all the APIs inherited from the first class

put those methods to a **public sealed** class

> I have other classes who inherit from that class.

use Interface of base class with virtual methods for that.

Comment: And call it Decorator Pattern :)